# CSS rectangular with one oval side

Tags: css

Is this possible to make with CSS? (Color is not important, just bottom side that is oval)

[image]

Comment: Just the bottom curve or curve+gradient?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
background-color: #60a0d0;
border-bottom-left-radius:50% 10%;
border-bottom-right-radius:50% 10%;
```

(with appropriate browser prefixes)

Comment: The curve is not perfect as one on the picture i posted (you can compare here http://imageshack.us/a/img72/4650/navchj.png), but anything's better than nothing! Thank you very much!

Comment: I've experiemented a little, its better with  border-bottom-left-radius:50% 20%;
border-bottom-right-radius:50% 20%; That's it, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can get any curve with an ellipse or circle, placed behind the main block:
http://jsfiddle.net/e9RLQ/1/

```
.box {
    position: relative;    
    background: #60a0d0;
}
.box:after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    width: 300%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: -292px 0 0 -100%;
    background: #60a0d0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: "";
}
```

The drawback here is the complexity of adding gradient background.